# DOS Command for Copying certain filetypes from one place to another

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation, copy, command

I have **5 different VPS with different OS** installed on them (All are Windows versions though) and when I am working on these different servers I usually save my work, ideas and important things to desktop in either `.txt` or `.xls` format. And new business contacts emailadresses  is automatically exported to desktop in `.csv` format (I made a bot for that).

Now to my problem/issue:

Since a while back I am using WinAutomation (WA), but I cannot figure out how to do the following thing in WA using a batch command (quicker than the normal copy function in WA):

I want to copy all `*.txt`, `*.xls` and `*.csv` from my desktop (location varies depending on Win OS) on all 5 servers into a dat file (using WA's `%SpecialFolder%` here) so I want it (all files with these extensions from the different desktop locations) to be copied into `%SpecialFolder%\myfiles.dat` (which later will be emailed to me, *that* I managed to do).

I suck at batch commands and I am new to WA, perhaps to make sure it work on all 5 servers (to get desktop despite placement of this) I assume `"%USERPROFILE%\desktop\"` but I am not sure....SO

You WinAutomation/batch pro's out there please help me asap so I can get more quality time with my beloved family ;)

Comment: Now what? DOS or Windows?

Comment: @0xC0000022L Did you read from the first to last line ;) ?

Comment: Many people use the word DOS when they mean the Windows command line processor `CMD.EXE`. I edited the question to use `batch` instead of `DOS`.

Comment: @aphoria Thanks for pointing that out i am not a programmer :) but here is WinAutomation's own description of it http://i.imgur.com/idTE3Kc.png

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate fileA and fileB to fileC you enter: 
"copy fileA + fileB fileC"

You can add more files together, to add all *.txt files you need to write a batch file.

A simple alternative is:
"type *.txt >> newfile.dat" which will work for binary files too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however since i am not a programmer but a salesmen perhaps the person answering needs to own or know about WA's different commands as well as batch/DOS, i am looking for a copy paste line ;) noobs rules right lol ?